# Optimal camera2 settings for minimum noise/high resolution image

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm implementing camera2 Android API in order to obtain bitmaps used for
OCR detection via the Tess-Two libray.

After doing some image processing, I am getting good results for math expressions that don't include fractions and radicals. However, my goal is to try to eliminate all possible
noise and obtain the highest resolution image possible.

I know that different camera devices on Android phones have different capabilities. I also know that there are over 100 variables I can set on my CaptureRequest object for the camera. Variables such as:

- Auto-White-Balance correction
- aberration modes
- flicker effects(none or at 50Hz or 60 Hz)
- Anti-banding
- optical image stabilization settings
- Auto-Exposure
- And the list is never ending.

It seems to me that you must be an expert at photography in order to select the 
best settings possible to guarantee the highest quality output from the camera2 API. I'm not an expert at photography. I would like to know if anyone can help me in deciding what would be some good settings to set on my capturerequest object in order to have the best quality output from the camera device. And, I know it is all dependent on the Camera quality the device is using.